# Strategy to design a cross platform web application

Tags: cordova, web, parse-platform

I need to design a web application which will be accessible through browser, iOS and android mobile phone. My solution is:

- parse.com as the server which provide data
- PhoneGap for the mobile application

But the problem is I have to upload and modify the PhoneGap code to my host for the browser to access. That means I may have two sets of similar but different source code.

The other solution is:

- parse.com or other node.js server
- Server site js (for example, express.js)
- The mobile application, browser shared the same code

The question is how I'm supposed to call server code directly in my PhoneGap application. (Of course, I can use write simple application with a web browser and hard code the link to my server. But I have to write two different applications in iOS and android. And the services like PhoneGap build can't be used in this case.)

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Why there are always some guys down voting somebody else's question without any reason? Hate them very much!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have misconceptions about what Phonegap/Cordova is. Cordova glues your html/css/js (html5) code to the native side. In order to have a mobile web solution (such as m.yoursite.com that serves to mobile browsers), you do not have to upload cordova to server nor do anything related to cordova. You still can use your html5 side, at least about 90% of it to use in the mobile web.

Also I don't understand your last paragraph, about calling server directly. You are going to do it in your js side (ajax, xhr, http) as you always do. Cordova does not even know or care about your server communication.

I would suggest using a mvvm framework such as angularjs (or emberjs, knockout, backbone, etc), develop your client side, then use cordova to connect that html5 site to native platforms as app. Your apps client code will only differ if you use native functionality (using cordova) which is pretty trivial to abstract away in web version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Maybe my English is not good enough to express  my situation clearly. I understand that I can write html/css/js code in my client side. It even doesn't matter if there is a server side or not. But my case is I need to communicate my server in parse.com. It's no problem to use parse javascript sdk to do this. But besides the mobile client side, I also have browser clients. Maybe let me rephrase my question as: Is it possible to write one set of code to be used by mobile client through PhoneGap and also by browser users?

Comment: Yes, they are both JavaScript, aren't they.